# insert an array into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array which I would like to insert into mysql database.

- Item[0] = Soccer
- Item[1] = Rugby
- Item[2] = Football
- Item[3] = Netball
- Item[4] = Hockey

I am using the following function to insert into the database, located in functions.php:

```
//Capture items 
    function item($register_data)
    {
        array_walk($register_data,'array_clean');

        $fields = ' '.implode(',',array_keys($register_data)).' ';
        $data = '\''.implode('\',\'',$register_data).'\'';

        //Insert user Data into the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO items ($fields) VALUES ($data)";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Now this is how I insert:

```
for($i =0;$i<4;$i++)
                {
                    $item = array($i = item[i]);        
                }


//Call the function to insert into the database
item($item);
```

This method doesn't seem to work.  Please assist

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: 1) Use `mysql_error()` to get hints to what went wrong. 2) Switch to mysqli or PDO as `mysql_x` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Doesn't work how? Also, `mysql_*` is deprecated... Check into PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: I dont get an error, but nothing gets inserted into database

Comment: What does your database look like? That array looks like a list of set of records rather than columns, so why are you inserting them as fields. Also arraykeys (0, 1, 2) are terrible names for your fields.

Comment: `echo` query. And see if it a valid `SQL`.

Comment: Don't do it, normalize your database instead; and your life will be easier in the future

Comment: The items table contains 2 columns: item_id(auto increment PRIMARY KEY, INT), and ItemName(VARCHAR).

Comment: if you want to add an array to your table you could serialize it

Comment: What does this line do? -> $item = array($i = item[i]);
IT contains a lot of meaningless stuff, always overwriting same variable, and also array($i = item[i]) is completely meaningless here, probably you wanted to do array($i => item[i]) instead?

Comment: Let me look into serialize.  This line stores data from HTML textfields into the php array called $item.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in serialize & deserialize functions (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) for that. You can pass any object or array to it, and it will return a serialized string, which you can store in a single field in the database.

Comment: I dont really wanna serialize the input data. I would like to insert it individually. One after Another

Answer (score 1):

Since your items table has two columns, one of which is `id` (auto increment) you're going to want to skip over it and only specify the second column `ItemName`. This is described in the mysql documentation on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Lets say you want to insert 5 sports in this table:

```
$sports[0] = "Soccer";
$sports[1] = "Rugby";
$sports[2] = "Football";
$sports[3] = "Netball";
$sports[4] = "Hockey";
```

You'll want the query to look something along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO items (ItemName) VALUES ('Soccer'), ('Rugby'), ('Football'), ('Netball'), ('Hockey');
```

The code would look something like this:

```
function insert($insert_data)
{
    $fields = implode(', ', $insert_data);
    $data = '(\''.implode('\'), (\'', $insert_data).'\')';

    //mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (ItemName) VALUES $data;");
    echo "INSERT INTO items (ItemName) VALUES $data;";
}

$sports = array();
$sports[0] = "Soccer";
$sports[1] = "Rugby";
$sports[2] = "Football";
$sports[3] = "Netball";
$sports[4] = "Hockey";

insert($sports);
```

You may also want to [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) the strings first and take a look at [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) since [mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is pretty outdated.

Comment: Nice Example. Let me try this

Comment: What if I dont have a static number of fields for the $sports array ?

Comment: @user1783675 You mean if the sports array has more than 5 sports? The insert function is going to generate a query depending on how many sports it has, as long as the array is larger than 1 it should be fine.

Comment: yes @Edward-a.  The number of sporting activities varies all the time. for user it can be 2, another 5 and another user 15.

Comment: @user1783675 As long as there is one or more sports in the array it should do the job.